# Como deletar todos os arquivos de um diretorio usando FileUtils.cleanDirectory();

Tags: java

Estou tentando excluir todos os arquivos de dentro de uma pasta, mas não deletar a pasta em si, me recomendaram utilizar o FileUtils.cleanDirectory(), porém, não consigo especificar a pasta que quero que ele exclua o conteúdo, meu comando está assim:

```
FileUtils.cleanDirectory("C:\PAYGO\RESP");
```

desta forma o netbeans dá erro dizendo que uma String não pode ser convertida em um File, então como eu poderia especificar a pasta?

Answer (score 0):

Lembre-se que o `\` é usado para sequências de escape. Tente usar `"C:\\PAYGO\\RESP"`.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou inserir também o `path` do diretório como se fosse um regex:

> C:\PAYGO\RESP*

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma:

```
File resp = new File("C:/PAYGO/RESP");

FileUtils.cleanDirectory(resp);
```

tive que criar um File e colocar o caminho da pasta dentro dele, mas obrigado a todos pela ajuda!